# What Is the Max Number of <script> Tags Allowed in Head of Document?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I'm writing a client side application using require.js to asynchronously load javascript assets. The application is very large, and instead of minifying the entire js app into one file, I'm loading features lazily - only when the user needs them. I've been looking online, but I can't seem to find an answer to the question "How many scripts are too many?" They're relatively small, with the size ranging from 50 - 200 lines of code each, unminified. The number of script tags loaded increases the more the user navigates through the application.

**Is there a limit imposed by HTML on how many script tags can appear in the head of a document?**

Comment: no, there's no real limits to html, but anything more than a few (say 10, max) script tags is getting into ludicrous territory.

Comment: Do make sure that the *initial* set of scripts that you need **is** combined and minified. Adding others as you go is fine, provided you're okay with the extra HTTP hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit imposed by the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) but you may run into practical limits in popular browsers. Make sure you test in all popular/supported browsers.

Comment: +1, but: *"but you may run into practical limits in popular browser"* No you won't. Browsers have no problem with hundreds of thousands of elements. Doesn't matter if they're `script` elements or other kinds of elements.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Perhaps there is no practical limit from a DOM tree parsing perspective, but from the network perspective, i.e. loading a large number of `.js` files referenced in `<script src="...js">` over HTTP, I suspect you would run into practical limits.

Comment: He said he's loading these as the user navigates, not all at once. All at once would just be dumb. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair enough.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'll combine and minify to initial scripts like @T.J.Crowder suggested, and lazy load the rest.